# Flutter Bloc: Bloc Event: Equatable: Classes can only extends other classes

Tags: flutter, dart, events, bloc, equatable

Playing around with Bloc in Flutter.
In the Bloc event, I faced a problem regarding Equatable.
At first, I cannot import `equatable` package: import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart'; The error says:
"The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part. Try removing other directives, or moving them to the library for which this is a part".

Later on, when I create the Event and extends Equatable, the error says:
"Classes can only extend other classes. Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause".

(FYI: I put into the `pubspec.yaml` the equitable dependency).

I will appreciate your assistance, as always!

[image: Equatable problem]

Answer (score 1):

> The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part. Try removing other directives, or moving them to the library for which this is a part.

That error message means you can't import any package from **bloc_event.dart** because **bloc_event.dart** is part of **bloc_bloc.dart**. Try to import the **equatable** package in **bloc_bloc.dart**. And don't forget to **flutter pub get**.

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'bloc_event.dart';

class BlocBloc ...
```

Comment: Hi @Yanuar. I added a comment with a picture, where problem still occurs. any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @RobsonGieret, where is your comment?

Answer (score 1):

It's returning an error because `bloc_event.dart` is part of `bloc_bloc.dart`.

Try to:

1. import the equatable package in `bloc_bloc.dart`
2. import your state class,
3. remove all the part imports
4. import them normally without the part.

   ```js
   import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
   class BlocBloc...
   ```